# Close c# application when video stops playing

Tags: c#, video

I am trying to figure out how to close my application when the video that the form plays stops playing.  Currently, the user clicks a button to bring up Form2.  The control for the video is set to force the video full screen, and start playing from the beginning of the video. I am using axWindowsMediaPlayer to provide the video.  I am also a complete neophyte when it comes to C#.

How would I get my application to close when the video stops playing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to detect when the media has ended, here is a tutorial on: ["Detect the End of Media - axWindowsMediaPlayer"](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_controls/tutorials/article.php/c16597/Tip-C--Detect-the-End-of-Media--axWindowsMediaPlayer.htm). Then you need to call `Close();` to close the form you are currently playing the media from.

Example (snippets from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562460%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

```
// Subscribe to the Play State Change event
player.PlayStateChange += 
  new AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEventHandler(player_PlayStateChange);
```

Then you need the event handler that can look like this:

```
private void player_PlayStateChange(object sender,
                                  AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
{
    // 8 = Media Ended
    if(e.newState == 8) { Close(); }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply!  As I said, I am very new to C#.  Where would I put your code to subscribe, please?  I tried looking at the tutorial, and the MSDN reference, and did not see a place to put that code.